# Possible to use a different set of hooks for a user or group in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

I am not sure if this is possible currently but is it possible to specify a separate set of hooks for a user or group (groups from the ACL extension).

I know you can specify the hooks on each user's machine individually but I would like to also place the hooks on the central repo (so that those hooks are ran when they push).

For example

say I have hooks for group A

```
[hooks]
pretxngroupchange.A=python:Group-A-hook.py:hook
```

for all of group A

and

```
[hooks]
pretxngroupchange.B=python:Group-B-hook.py:hook
```

If someone from group A pushes, I don't want the hooks for group B to be triggered

Is this possible?  Even if I can't do it by groups (which I think Mercurial should pick up Os-level groups), is it possible for Hg to run it per user?

Comment: dis has a fine answer below.  Check out the AclExtension that shipped with Mercurial for an example of a hook that behaves differently based on user and group.

Comment: Could you point me to the resource?  I can't seem to find an example of the ACL hook firing a specific hook for each user

Comment: That's the point.  It's not a different hook for each user, it's a different code path within the same hook for each user.  For ACL it's just returning true or false, but those those lines could be replaced with whatever "doing something" you want.  Once you have the user info in a hook you can branch the logical flow as you would in any imperative programming language.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single script which looks up users by name and performs a different activity based on the user. In order to avoid having to update the script for new users, you could revision a user list in an Hg repo and read the latest version of the repo inside this hook.

I'm not sure that this qualifies as a "good idea", but it might work if you can't find another solution.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't sure if there was an out of the box feature that did that for me.